# Elements overlap/disappear on window resize

Tags: html, css

How do I stop the elements from crossing over and disappearing when I resize the browser? I faced this issue while working on this website www.alejandrotommasi.com

Comment: can u share the jsfiddle file instead of the web url. They disappear because of your css.

Comment: It is very difficult to understand your code via inspect the website, can you please share your html and css for better understand your code.

Comment: Start with https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it, and then go read [ask].

Comment: I tried but this site blocks my code :'v

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can use width property - set it to X% or Xvw. Elements will shrink then you resize the browser.

```
div {
  width: 50%;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZZeyQZ)